# I am trying to create a new GitHub account and the captha is not allowing me to create

Tags: github

I tried stuff like using other browsers, deleting the browser history, etc but whenever I solve the puzzle early it says wrong or the time has run out. I am inserting the puzzle for your reference.

[image]

Comment: You should probably contact Github support.

Comment: Which box did you pick?

Comment: Hi, I used voice recognition to do the confirmation but something was wrong with the puzzle. Even after changing browsers or trying after one week, it was the same puzzle.